# My img src is not showing my picture in html

Tags: html

This one has me scratching my head. My other pictures are working except my banner image. I am unable to figure out why it is not appearing, I have tried `../images/topb.jpg` and `../topb.jpg`. Any suggestions will be great! Here is my code:

```
<img src="images/topb.jpg" alt="topb"/>
```

So the directory hierarchy is as follows(couldn't post a picture not enough rep yet):

```
redesign
 ├── Css
 ├── images
 |      └── topb.jpg
 └── home.html
```

Comment: Are you running this locally or on a web server?  If on a server, did the image file upload correctly?  Try going directly to the image url to check that the file is ok and shows in your browser.

Comment: And to the point of it being from a Web server... first off, is your capitalization correct?  The easiest thing to do is to not worry about the HTML, and hit the URL directly:  http://sever/images/tobp.jpg.  Debug from there, which could be a host of issues depending on your environment.

Comment: Does your image file have read permission?

Comment: To answer your questions which I should of mentioned earlier, I am trying to run this through the web server. I tried the image from the URL directly and it does load properly. And yes I also have read permission on there. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you have .htaccess file? If yes check is there any restriction? Why cant you try with absolute path instead of relative path?

Comment: @EllyB. I had this issue once.. Since the image size was very big it was not  loeaded.. Check that too

Comment: I do have a .htaaccess file, didn't seem to be any restrictions. However just using the absolute path seemed to fix it as now the image is showing up.